# Can't scroll to bottom of a cell in the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

In my datagridview, there is one cell that contains quite a few rows of text:
[image]

If you notice in the image, the scrollbar is all the way at the bottom, but if you look closely at the 'Text' cell, there is text that isn't completely displayed.  I am using this code (below) to autoformat the rows in the grid:

```
// Autoformat of cells.
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

What else can I try so that all the text is visible in the cell?

Comment: When `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set? Could you make a test button which will set `AutoSizeRowsMode` when clicked? Still not fit?

Comment: appr. how many lines are missing?

Comment: Looks like two lines are missing.  The one that's barely visible, and the one below it.

Comment: How did you scroll? In code or manually?

Comment: Manually.  I'm thinking the problem is that the contents of this cell are bigger the the actual form that contains the grid and somehow, or other, that's causing the problem.

Comment: Ah. Is it also greater than the DGV's height?

Comment: @TaW Yes, it is greater than the DGV's height.  I'm thinking that because of this, there isn't much I can do about it.

Comment: this is a very frustrating problem.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your image, we can see that the scroll bar is relative to the form and not to the datagridview.

Modify the `Dock` property of the `DataGridView` to `DockStyle.Fill` to see the datagridview's scroll bar instead of the form one.

Comment: wouldnt have seen that! :)

Comment: you save my life